# I looking for a software package for dubbing with source voices

Tags: artificial-intelligence, deep-learning, voice-recognition

I'm looking for a software package for dubbing a movie. I have part 1 of the movie done by letting al the voiceovers speak every sentence in.

Now we have part 2 finished but would like to dubb the movie from English to Dutch bases on the voices of that were used in part 1.

Is there some software that can use AI to generate the voices based on part 1 (a little like deep fake)?